# Is the sum of an images histogram not just the area of the image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I've seen a few times in scientific papers people referring to the sum of an image's histogram, and then in the reference source code they're using the python `sum()` function over an openCV's `calcHistogram` output. Surely this just equal to the area of the image and it's probably more computationally efficient just to multiply the image width and height?

example:

```
def clip_histogram_(self, hists, threshold = 10.0):
        all_sum = sum(hists)
        threshold_value = all_sum / len(hists) * threshold
        ...
```

Where the histogram here is just an array of length 255 with the index representing the color and the representing integer being the frequency of that color.

Unless Python does some magic with their `sum` function, this can't be an efficient way of doing things?

Comment: "Surely this just equal to the area of the image" -- not at all. why do you think so ? (the formula computes (somethink like) the mean pixel value, this is not related to image size)

Comment: Histograms are computed based on pixel intensities at every location. Area is just the product of height and width of the image **independent of pixel intensity**. Two images of the same size/area can have different histogram representations

Comment: @berak: yes at all. You confuse with the histogram centroid.

Comment: I included the second line of the function as some context, I'm specifically referring to the `sum` function here as being equal to the width*height of the image. Right now, @YvesDaoust's answer is making the most sense. A bin is incremented for each pixel in the image, so it would only follow that the sum of all bins is equal to the total number of pixels.

Comment: The sum over the full histogram for each color is the same as the sum of gray level values in each channel respectively over the full image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the variable `hists` indeed contains the histogram of an image, you are quite right, the bins sum to the image size.

It appears that the function does not receive the image, so this is an alternative way to get that size.

---

Though it may seem a waste to perform this inefficient operation, its cost is usually neglectable compared to the time to compute the histogram itself.